# Why WindowStateChange event does not work with me

Tags: c++, qt, events, qt5

I want when change the window state from state to another, for example: `WindowMaximized`, `WindowMinimized`, `WindowFullScreen`, when change the  window state performs something.

**The function used**

```
void Widget::WindowStateChange(QEvent *event){
    if (event->WindowStateChange == Qt::WindowMaximized) {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "", "Something happen.");
    }
}
```

There is nothing happening when implement the previous function.

Comment: Are you trying this with your widget used like the window or is this child widget of some another widget? I guess, the needed events comes only to top level widget and should be propagated to the required place by you.

Comment: @N1ghtLight: Yes, for parent `widget` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is never called. There are several virtual methods in `QWidget` which are called when some events happen: `actionEvent`, `changeEvent`, `closeEvent` and [other](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#protected-functions).

You can reimplement them and process these events.

To catch window state changes method [changeEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#changeEvent) is used.

It is called when not only window state is changed, but also font, style etc. That is why you need to filter an event you want to process. You can do it by checking `event->type()`.

```
void Widget::changeEvent(QEvent* e)
{
   if (e->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange)
   {
      QWindowStateChangeEvent* ev = static_cast<QWindowStateChangeEvent*>(e);
      if (!(ev->oldState() & Qt::WindowMaximized) && windowState() & Qt::WindowMaximized)
      {
          QMessageBox::information(this, "", "Window has been maximized");
      }
   }
   QWidget::changeEvent(e);
}
```